# Prove that every nontrivial tournament has at least one serf.

Tags: graph-theory

> **Serf definition**: A vertex $z$ in a nontrivial tournament is called a **serf** if for every vertex $x$ distinct from $z$, either $x$ adjacent to $z$ or $x$ is adjacent to a vertex that is adjacent to $z$.

Prove that every nontrivial tournament has at least one serf.

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, but a tournament is  an oriented complete graph, and in a complete graph of order $n$ every vertex un-oriented adjacent to $n-1$ other vertex, so the only way for a vertex to not be a serf is that vertex has to be a source.

Assume the contrary that there exists a tournament that doesn't have any serf, then that tournament has every vertex is a source, which is impossible, thus every tournament must have at least one serf.

is my argument acceptable?

Comment: Here the statement that $x$ is adjacent to $y$ means that the $xy$ edge is directed from $x$ to $y$. In a transitive tournament, for instance, the overall winner is not a serf: no vertex is adjacent *to* him, because all other vertices are adjacent *from* him. In game terms, you’re a serf if every other player either beat you, or beat someone who beat you.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I fixed my answer would you check it for me please.

Comment: It’s not that simple, I’m afraid: *not a serf* is not the same as *is a source*. Take a tournament in which $A$ beats $B$ and $C$, and $B$ beats $C$. Then $B$ is neither a serf nor a source. (Of course $C$ is a serf, so this isn’t a counterexample to the theorem, but it does show that your argument doesn’t work.)

Comment: Maybe, this definition is easier to understand : A vertex $x$ is a serf, if the directed distance to all other vertices is at most $2$. Or did I understand something wrong ?

Comment: @Peter if that is the definition of the serf then the serf just have to be the vertex that have maximum score , any every tournament has a vertex of maximum score, right?

Comment: @Peter: You have it backwards: the directed distance *to* $x$ from any other vertex is at most $2$.

Comment: I am not so firm with tournaments, what is a source, for example ?

Comment: @Peter: In a directed graph a source is a vertex whose in-degree is zero: all edges at the vertex are directed away from it.

Comment: And the maximum score of a vertex ? What is the relationship to its in-degree and out-degree ?

Comment: a score of a vertex is the out degree of that vertex in a tournament

Comment: But why is the distance of a vertex with maximum score to any other vertex at most $2$ ?

Comment: @Peter let say $u$ is the one that have max score, if every other vertices $v_i$ adjacent from $u$ then $d(u,v_i)=1$. If there exist some vertex $w$ that adjacent from  $v_i$ then $d(u,w)=2$. There is one more part by contradiction to show $d$ can't be bigger than $2$

Comment: This question has also been discussed here https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3678/every-tournament-has-a-dominant-player

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: I’ll phrase this in terms of a real round-robin tournament rather than a graph. Let $p$ be a player with the smallest possible score, and let $B$ be the set of players beaten by $p$. Use the fact that every $b\in B$ has a score that is at least as big as $p$’s to show that every $b\in B$ beats someone who beats $p$. Thus, a player with minimal score must be a serf.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  Consider the King Chicken theorem.  This is almost the exact opposite of that theorem.  The line of reasoning that proves one vertex must be a king chicken should also apply for a 'serf'.  Recall that a 'King Chicken' dominates all vertices by a distance of at most 2.  That is, if $u$ is a king chicken, then either $u$ beats all vertices, or for any vertex $v$, if $u$ does not dominate $v$, then $u$ dominates some vertex $x$ such that $x$ dominates $v$.  I reiterate, a serf is the direct opposite of a king chicken. I hope that helps.